# Submit button not working in infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a list in SharePoint and, I customized the form. I have an issue when I  submit the data to SharePoint list. When I click on submit button InfoPath form I am getting following error:

"Infopath cannot submit because it contains errors. Errors are marked with either a red asterisk(required fields) or a red, dashed border (invalid values). Any Idea appreciated

NB. I tried using data connection, but not working.

Comment: I followed this. The error I am getting is due to SameSite attribute setting. Where can I change SameSite setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following steps:

Right click the submit button--->Click properties-->Under Action dropdown select Submit--->Click Submit Option--->Select Allow User to submit this form
[image]

[image]