# submit button is not functioning

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We have a sharepoint form that one user specifically can complete the necessary fields but when she clicks on the submit button nothing happens.  She has disabled her pop up blocker.  She uses internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying SharePoint form -  is it infopath form submit button? If yes, please check the below setting using the below URL :

[Submit button not working in info path form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215731/submit-button-not-working-in-info-path-form/215733)

And if this is a SharePoint default list form, try to check whether the javascript is enabled in your browser setting.  Then try opening in different different browsers like chrome, edge. If still does not work try to debug the page from your browser F12 tool, and see what happens when you click on submit button.